# Bus error: 10 while trying to mess with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, macos, emacs, bus-error

I'm just playing with arrays and I've written this tiny thing in Emacs (OSX) and I'm getting a `Bus error: 10` when I try to run it. I don't know why that is, maybe someone can show me...

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{    
  int array[3][3];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; i < 3; j++)
      {
        array[i][j] = j + i;
      }
    }
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {
        std::cout << array[i][j];
      }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riiiiight here:

```
  for (int j = 0; i < 3; j++)
```

I think you want a `j` there in the middle.

```
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
```

Comment: That's embarrassing. Thanks for pointing that out. Now to move onto the third dimension...

Comment: Do you all have your THREE D GLASSES?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sN3UnhrEU6Y